# how to view uiimages saved to phphotolibrary?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I've written a Swift program that saves UIImages to a PHPhotoLibrary.  I've stepped through the program with the debugger and the program appears to complete without error.

However, I'm trying to find a way to validate that the program actually saved the UIImage to the PHPhotoLibrary.  When I run this program on my Mac will it create the PHPhotoAlbum with the name I provided somewhere on my hard disk that I can access after the program completes?  If so then where is this located?

Otherwise, is the PHPhotoAlbum only created within the context of the program at runtime?  And then the emulator clears this from memory when the program exits?  If this is the case then is there a way for me to view the image in the photo album that was created?

Comment: You can view the Photos app in simulator to verify - just press command+shift+H to go to home screen, swipe over to Photos, and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just open up the Photos app, and your images should be there.